# Spike feature with non-Office programs

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, copy-paste

I learned today of the Microsoft Word [spike feature](http://techadvisory.org/2014/05/the-spike-words-unknown-feature). This seems handy,
however I would be interested to use it outside of Microsoft Office. That is to
say, I would like to copy/paste multiple texts from non-Office programs.

Does any version of Windows have this feature, or a program available to enable
it?

Comment: It seems to me just a simplistic clipboard management feature. Ever heard of `ditto`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the program [CopyQ](http://hluk.github.io/CopyQ). CopyQ automatically saves each copy to its queue, but has no built in way to paste everything.

However you can
[create a command](http://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/issues/410) to do this:

```ini
[Command]
Name=Paste all
Command="
    copyq:
    var z = ''
    while (count()) {
      z = str(read(0)) + '\\n' + z
      remove(0)
    }
    copy(z)
    paste()"
GlobalShortcut=Ctrl+Shift+V
```